# node-q when using or not .done()

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, q

I'm having nodejs memory leak.

In the documentacion: http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#the-end

```
return foo()
.then(function () {
    return "bar";
});
```

Or, end it.

```
foo()
.then(function () {
    return "bar";
})
.done();
```

**My doubt, is when using or not .done()**.

Cases(4): look to ***"I must use here .done()?"***

```
function demo1(){
return Q.Promise(function (done, fail) {
   ... some code ...
});***"I must use here .done()?"***
}

function demo2(){
return Q.fcall(function () {
   ... some code ...
}).then(function () {
   ... some code ...
});***"I must use here .done()?"***
}
```

The next function are used with express

```
app.route('/xpto').post(demo3);
        .get(demo4);


function demo3(req, res){
return Q.fcall(function () {
... some assert...
}).then(function () {
    return Q.all([ teste1,teste2 ])
   .spread(function (teste1_res,teste2_res) {
        ... some code ...
    });***"I must use here .done()?"***
}).fail(function (error) {
   ... some code ...
   res.status(403).send({"error": true});
});***"I must use here .done()?"***
}


function demo4(req, res){
Q.fcall(function () { /*"This is similar to demo3, is "return" required?"*
... some assert...
}).then(function () {
   return promisefunction();***"I must use here .done()?"***
   ... some code ...
}).then(function () {
   res.json({});
});***"I must use here .done()?"***
}
```

Comment: Hi user338840, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is quite difficult to understand - exactly what memory leak problems are you getting, and which version of the code is getting the problems?

Comment: Hi, first of all, i want discover the correct usage of "done()", in multiple cases.   Second, my memory leak, is in string's. I dont know if is wrong usage or not of "done()". I think is because using Mustache inside promise(Q). On the heapdump, the strings are related with Mustache.